# Resources on the caveman Caro-Kann

Tags: opening, caro-kann

The caveman Caro-Kann goes:

```
[fen ""]
1. e4 c6 2. d4 d5 3.e5 Bf5 4. h4 h5 5. Bg5!?
```

Any anotated games, resourses, books, etc, are apreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about accepting answers to your questions? It looks like you are posting a lot of questions without accepting answers.

Comment: I have accepted answers in several of them. In those which I do not like any of the answers, I might have not accepted. I might have missed a question or two though. Will you please post here which one are you referencing to?

Answer (score 7):

There is some analysis at the Kenilworthian blog. See http://www.kenilworthchessclub.org/games/java/2007/caro-adv-h4.htm
http://www.kenilworthchessclub.org/games/java/2011/cavewoman.htm
http://www.kenilworthchessclub.org/games/java/2013/complete-caveman.htm
http://kenilworthian.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/the-complete-caveman-caro-kann_20.html

Download for the PGN:
http://www.rci.rutgers.edu/~goeller/kenilworth-pgn/complete-caveman.pgn

and also analysis by Dennis Monokroussos here:
http://www.thechessmind.net/storage/chess-posts/anand_shirov_leon2011_day3.htm